# Keras - dense_3 has a wrong dense (6,) but should be (1,)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm learning neural networks and I want to create a model that predicts a value of the domain. 
To simplify, I created a `drank` which can be 0,1,2,3,4 or 5.

Things I do:

1. modify the dataframe, filter data etc
2. tokenize the domain names to 2dimensional array of integers (based on chars)
3. split to X,y train,test
4. compile model

The output should be from 0 to 5 integers so the last layer should have (6,) shape in my opinion. But obviously, there is something wrong.

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape
>   (6,) but got array with shape (1,)

Do you know what to do?

```
from datetime import timedelta, date, datetime
import json
import locale

from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras_preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras_preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
LISTINGS_JSON_PATH = '....path to json'

def get_drank(rank):
    if rank>5:
        return 5
    return rank

with open(LISTINGS_JSON_PATH) as f:
    d = json.loads(f.read())

today = datetime.combine(date.today(), datetime.min.time())
df = pd.DataFrame(d['data'])
df = df[['domainName', 'auctionEndTime', 'numberOfBids']]
df['domainName'] = df['domainName'].str.lower()
df['auctionEndTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['auctionEndTime'].str.slice(0, 10), format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['days_to_end'] = df['auctionEndTime'].apply(lambda x: (x - today).days + 1)
df['rank'] = df['numberOfBids'] * (df['days_to_end'])
df['drank'] = df['rank'].apply(lambda x:get_drank(x))
df = df[(df['rank'] != 0.0)|(df['days_to_end']==0.0)]

tk = Tokenizer(num_words=None, char_level=True)
tk.fit_on_texts(df['domainName'])
sequences = tk.texts_to_sequences(df['domainName'])
sequences = pad_sequences(sequences, padding='post')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test  = train_test_split(sequences, df['drank'], test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

print(X_train)
print(X_test)

model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(sequences[0].__len__(),)),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(6, activation='softmax'),
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', )

hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                 batch_size=32, epochs=10,
                 validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

OUT:

```
[[15  5 11 ...  0  0  0]
 [11 21  6 ...  0  0  0]
 [12  1  3 ...  0  0  0]
 ...
 [ 8  1  1 ...  0  0  0]
 [ 3  1  8 ...  0  0  0]
 [20  1 14 ...  0  0  0]]
187869    0
14522     0
191921    0
38952     0
273009    0
         ..
117583    0
73349     0
416735    5
267336    0
128037    0
```

Answer (score 0):

> The output should be from 0 to 6 integers so the last layer should have (4,) shape in my opinion.

I'm not sure what you mean  by  this statement. Do you mean shape (1,) or shape(7,)?

First you will need to determine whether `drank` should be *ordinal* or *nominal*.

In the ordinal case, this means that the order of integer values for the output label matters. For instance, if the output is either 1 or 0 where 1 means HIGH and 0 means LOW, then the ordering `0 < 1` makes sense logically. Then if your output shape `Y_train, Y_test` is shape (1,), you will need to change the loss function to `loss=sparse_categorical_cross_entropy`.

In the nominal case, the order does not matter. For instance, if y takes on values between APPLE, ORANGE, and BANANA, we might have an array like:

```
# Original data: 0=apple, 1=orange, 2=banana
y = [ [2], [0], ...]
# One hot encoded
y = [ [0,0,1],  # For banana
      [1,0,0],  # for apple
    ]
```

where `APPLE < BANANA` does not make any sense. This can be done by using `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` and transforming your targets into the shape above, and your model architecture should work.

Comment: Sorry I meant 0,1,2,3,4,5 so shape (6,)

Comment: In that case, the error is because the loss function `categorical_cross_entropy` predicts outputs of shape (6,) but only received a single integer target to train against. If the problem you are trying to solve is nominal, one hot encode the target labels and it should work.